# SWIG error for Python target wrapping C++ class

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to wrap a C++ library, that is accessed via a single class, with Python (3.6.2) using SWIG.

The C++ library can be found here:
https://github.com/Navigator-Data/navdb-clients/tree/master/lang_clients/cpp_client

Here's my cpp_client_api.i file:

```
/* File : cpp_client_api.i */
%module cpp_client_api

%{
#include "../cpp_client/cpp_client_api.hpp"
%}

%include "../cpp_client/cpp_client_api.hpp"
```

After generating the .py file I found that I had to rename it to have an underscore as a prefix.

When I run a test Python program making use of the newly generated .py file I get this error:

```
python ./n*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./navdb_python_client_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    from _cpp_client_api import CppClientApi
  File "../_cpp_client_api.py", line 98, in <module>
    class CppClientApi(_object):
  File "../_cpp_client_api.py", line 135, in CppClientApi
    __swig_destroy__ = _cpp_client_api.delete_CppClientApi
AttributeError: module '_cpp_client_api' has no attribute 'delete_CppClientApi'
```

It looks like delete_CppClientApi is a generic function used for calling the class' destructor. The original class doesn't have a destructor that I've specifically written, I'm not sure if that's a problem. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using distutils to compile the Swig wrapper code:

python setup.py build_ext --inplace

Jason